# Ion-select issue with server data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to show options which are coming from the server. When I click on the select option, I am getting the previous value on the first click, and I am getting the updated value on the second click.

I am making an app where the user has a page where they can change the option and save that data to the server. But when options are updating it's coming to the option on the second click, the previous value is showing on the first click.

Here is the code:

```
dropDownListOne() {

  this.regService.dropDownOne(this.uId)
    .subscribe((info) => {
      this.ddOneData = info;
      var array = this.ddOneData;
      var val: string = (array[array.length - 1].dropdown1);
      this.options = [];      
      this.data = val;
      Object.keys(val).forEach(option => { if (val[option]!= "") 
     this.options.push(val[option])});                      
  })

  console.log(this.options)
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="option" placeholder="Select Option" (click)="dropDownListOne()">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>        
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ionChange` on the ion-select instead of `click`.

This will trigger `dropDownListOne()` whenever the selected option changes:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="option" placeholder="Select Option" (ionChange)="dropDownListOne()">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: after usin ionchange , service is not getting trggered , due to this , no value is changing in option